# Need to write a simple code in matlab of training sequence or zadoff Chu sequence for my OFDM signal-synchronization

Tags: fft, ofdm, ifft, synchronization, channel

I have written a complete code, in matlab, for my ofdm signal for the transmitter and receiver. Now I want to transmit my ofdm signal via wireless channel using SDR.

Now, I need to combine a simple and efficient synchronization-code to my ofdm-code to perform the following functions or tasks:

1- Time offset correction (detecting the start of my frame)
2- Phase Offset correction.
3- Frequency offset correction
4- Channel estimation and equalization.

How can I write such simple code in matlab for synchronization sequence!

Comment: The formulas for the Zadoff-Chu sequence are in Robert Heath's intro to wireless textbook.

Comment: Why "or zadoff chu". Either Tx is using Zadoff Chu or it is not. If Tx is using it, then Rx needs to do synchronization using Zadoff Chu. There is no "or", there is only "does require". What protocol are you using, 802.11b/ac/?/ or LTE?, or 802.16, or what?

Comment: I am transmitting a simple 802.11a OFDM signal. I read that I can use short and long training sequence. How can I perform the four tasks mentioned above with those sequences mathematically in matlab at the receiver!

Comment: Just for the record, is the transmitter using Zadoff Chu for synchronization. If not, then the receiver does not need to be concerned about it. I think you should break down the question into, say, four questions, and then show what problem you are having.

Comment: If you are not requiring Zadoff Chu, then this link may help you. https://openofdm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: 802.11a is very old standard. I didn't think it was being used today. In general, 802.11 does not use Zadoff Chu. If you want to go with Zadoff Chu, consider using LTE standard instead.